# Rendering a CAShapeLayer within custom UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have a custom `UIView` within a custom `tableViewCell`.  I'm trying to render two `CAShapeLayers` but nothing is showing up.

```
-(void) setUpLayers
{
if (!self.blueWave) {

    self.blueWave = [self createShapeLayer];

    self.blueWave.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

    self.redWave = [self createShapeLayer];
    self.redWave.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    [self.layer addSublayer:self.blueWave];
    [self.layer insertSublayer:self.redWave above:self.blueWave];

    [self render]; 
    } 
} 


- (CAShapeLayer *) createShapeLayer {
    CAShapeLayer* layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    layer.lineWidth = 2;
    layer.fillColor = nil;


    return layer;
}
```

This code works fine when its placed within `layoutSubviews` or `layoutSublayersOfLayer` in my custom `UIView` class, but not within my custom method above.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell what

```
[self createShapeLayer]
```

is doing, but be sure you are setting the **CAShapeLayer's frame** to something like **self.bounds**. If you are using *self.frame*, there is the possibility that the layers are just being rendered off-screen.

**Alternatively**, I've used the following code which might be similar to what you're looking to do

```
CAShapeLayer *rectangle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *rectanglePath=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
rectangle.path=rectanglePath.CGPath;
rectangle.fillColor = nil;
rectangle.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
rectangle.lineWidth = 2.0;
rectangle.opacity = 1.0;
[layer addSublayer:rectangle];
```

Be sure that at the point you are creating this shapeLayer that your bounds actually has size to it as well.

Comment: I tried doing `self.redWave.frame = self.bounds` but no success.  Is there somewhere specific I should be implementing this?

Comment: Interesting, I've done this many times before and the code you've posted appears correct. Is it possible to take a look at the createShapeLayer method?